# Erro "Fatal error: Uncaught Error:" em banco de dados

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Estou realizando meu primeiro banco de dados (usando um hospital como exemplo) através do phpmyadmin, e o seguinte erro está sendo gerado ao realizar tentativa de cadastro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function redirecionarCadastro() in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\projeto_hospital\salvar-hospital.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\projeto_hospital\index.php(66): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\projeto_hospital\salvar-hospital.php on line 9

A página que informa  que está ocorrendo o erro é a "salvar-hospital.php" abaixo:

```
<?php
    switch ($_REQUEST["acao"]) {
        case 'cadastrar':
            $sql = "INSERT INTO hospital (nome_hospital) VALUES ('".$_POST ["nome_hospital"]."')";

            $res = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

            redirecionarCadastro("consultar-hospital.php",$res);

            if($res==true){
                print "<div class='alert alert-success'>O cadastro foi realizado com sucesso! </div>";
            }else{
                print "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Não foi possível efetuar o cadastro! </div>";
            }

        break;

        case 'editar':
            $sql = "UPDATE hospital SET nome_hospital='".$_POST["nome_hospital"]."' WHERE id_hospital = ".$_POST["id_hospital"];

            $res = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

            redirecionarEditar("consultar-hospital",$res);
        break;

        case 'excluir':
            $sql = "DELETE FROM hospital WHERE id_hospital = ".$_REQUEST["id_hospital"];

            $res = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

            redirecionarExcluir("consultar-hospial",$res);
        break;
    }
?>

A página "index.php" segue abaixo: 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Hospital</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hospital</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Início</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Hospital
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="?page=cadastrar-hospital">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="?page=consultar-hospital">Consultar</a>
        </div>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Médico
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consultar</a>
        </div>
      </li> 
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Paciente
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cadastrar</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Consultar</a>
        </div>
      </li> 
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <?php
      include ("config.php");
      switch (@$_REQUEST ["page"]) {
        case 'cadastrar-hospital':
          include ("cadastrar-hospital.php"); 
          break;
        case 'consultar-hospital':
          include ("consultar-hospital.php"); 
          break;
        case 'salvar-hospital':
          include ("salvar-hospital.php");
          break;
        default:
          include ("main.php"); 
      }

    ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No trecho de código que você postou não existe a definição da função `redirecionarCadastro`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu erro é justamente na linha 9 do código apresentado, pois nela você chama a função `redirecionarCadastro("consultar-hospital.php",$res);` que não é definida em nenhum outro ponto do código. Essa função está em outro arquivo .php do seu projeto? Se for o caso você precisa dar um `include` nesse arquivo antes de chamar a função.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, realmente estava faltando o include.